# Accessing a DOM element attribute to set a global variable

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor and I'm setting the editor's base path by setting the global variable named CKEDITOR_BASEPATH like this:

```
var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = $('#ckeditor').data('basepath');
```

Now my question is, is it safe to access the data dash attribute of a DOM element this way? I'm doing it like this because I'm trying to avoid hard coding my URL in my script file and I can't really put this inside the jquery ready function as CKEditor requires that it should be a global variable. It's working right now in my local but I'm not sure if this can cause an issue later.

Comment: Since I'm not operating inside the dom ready function, I'm wondering if the dom element I'm accessing is already accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is risky because it assumes that:

1. jQuery is already loaded.
2. Element of `id="ckeditor"` has already been parsed.
3. CKEditor hasn't use the `CKEDITOR_BASEPATH` variable yet.

Lots of constraints. Different browsers may do different things here. It's hard to tell because you didn't provide any information about **how** scripts are loaded (static or dynamically?) and what is the **order**. Still, the solution, as I guess is very simple because your code suggests that the element looks like:

```
<element id="ckeditor" data-basepath="there/is/your/path" />
```

...and since it is rendered in the template more or less like the following (let's assume PHP):

```
<element id="ckeditor" data-basepath="<?php echo $path ?>" />
```

...why don't you render the correct `<script>` tag on the top of the template (in `<head>`) instead?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '<?php echo $path ?>';
</script>
```

...and the problem is solved.

> I'm doing it like this because I'm trying to avoid hard coding my URL

Nothing is hardcoded with this approach. No problems with the order of things. No more worries about DOM.

**P.S.**: The problem you have is described in the official [developers guide](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Specifying_the_Editor_Path).